# How to export google chart in pdf?

Tags: pdf, charts, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I have draw google chart. Now, I want to put button to save the chart in pdf format. I do look from here [Save google charts as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102992/save-google-charts-as-pdf) and other questions available in stack but it doesn't work.

Print png image by google chart already used but it just open a new tab with the png image but it doesnt open the save as pdf window for user.

Do anyone knows any ways to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to create a PDF

use method `addImage` to add the chart's image uri to the pdf

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart', 'table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
    [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
    [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
    [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
  var btnSave = document.getElementById('save-pdf');

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    btnSave.disabled = false;
  });

  btnSave.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.addImage(chart.getImageURI(), 0, 0);
    doc.save('chart.pdf');
  }, false);

  chart.draw(data, {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 24,
      left: 36,
      right: 12,
      top: 48,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    },
    height: 600,
    title: 'chart title',
    width: 600
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<input id="save-pdf" type="button" value="Save as PDF" disabled />
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you..but may I know the '0,0' in this code " doc.addImage(chart.getImageURI(), 0, 0);" means what?

Comment: is it automatically convert to pdf? I want to create button to export to pdf.

Comment: Thanks @WHiteHat for your solutions and time. Really appreciate it. The chart can be saved as pdf. I just need to add some additional information for the saved file. Thumbs up!!

Comment: oh, forgot about the `0,0` -- those are the `x,y` coordinates where to place the image on the pdf page...

Comment: The image a little bit blurr, can it be adjust?

Comment: never mind @WhiteHat, maybe because the scale.. thanks

Comment: Hi, @WhiteHat. Do you mind to look into this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577794/how-to-solve-repeating-dialog-box-save-as-pdf. I need to put the button in selection chart, but something not right.

Comment: How can you keep the ratio of the image in the PDF file?

Comment: have you tried setting the height & width in the pdf?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/) to create pdf of google chart with  store images,

Step 1. create.php

Use google method chart.getImageURI() to get image url then store into the variable after using jquery to submit form.

```
      <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
              ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', ],
              ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],
              ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
              ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ]
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
              bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
              legend: 'none',
            };
        // google chart 1
             var g_chart_1 = document.getElementById('g_chart_1');
             var g_chart_1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(g_chart_1);
                g_chart_1.draw(data, options);

            var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(chart_div);

            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
             chart_div.innerHTML = '<img style="display:none" src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '" class="img-responsive">';
             console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
            });

            chart.draw(data, options);

        // google chart 2
        var g_chart_2 = document.getElementById('g_chart_2');
              var g_chart_2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(g_chart_2);
        g_chart_2.draw(data, options);

        var chart_div1 = document.getElementById('chart_div1');
            var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(chart_div1);
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'ready', function () {

              chart_div1.innerHTML = '<img style="display:none" src="' + chart1.getImageURI() + '" class="img-responsive">';

              console.log(chart_div1.innerHTML);
            });

            chart1.draw(data, options);

        }
        </script>

      <div class="container" id="Chart_details">
          <div id='chart_div'></div><div id='g_chart_1'></div>
          <div id='chart_div1'></div><div id='g_chart_2'></div>
      </div>
          <div align="center">
             <form method="post" id="new_pdf" action="createchartpdf.php">
              <input type="hidden" name="hidden_div_html" id="hidden_div_html" />
              <button type="button" name="create_pdf" id="create_pdf" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Create PDF</button>
             </form>
            </div>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#create_pdf').click(function(){
        $('#hidden_div_html').val($('#Chart_details').html());
        $('#new_pdf').submit();
       });
      });
      </script>

      </body>
      </html>
```

step 2. createchartpdf.php

Get HTML data to get images url and store into the images folder, and then retrieve images and content.

print into pdf using mpdf. This is work with live server to print images.

```
        <?php

        if(isset($_POST["hidden_div_html"]) && $_POST["hidden_div_html"] != '')
        {

            $html = $_POST["hidden_div_html"];
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            @$doc->loadHTML($html);
            $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
            $i=1;
            $result='';
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $file_name = 'images/google_chart'.$i.'.png';
                    $img_Src=$tag->getAttribute('src');
                        file_put_contents($file_name, file_get_contents($img_Src));
                $res= '<img src="images/google_chart'.$i.'.png">';
                $result.=$res;
              $i++;
            }

            //include make_pdf
            include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");
            $mpdf=new mPDF();

            $mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
            $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

            $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; // 1 or 0 - whether to indent the first level of a list
            $mpdf->WriteHTML($result);
            $mpdf->Output();
        }

        ?>
```