# Export Google Chart to PDF using Cloudformatter, generates blank PDF

Tags: jquery, pdf, google-visualization, css-to-pdf

I'm trying to export google chart to the PDF file. I'm using *xepOnline.jqPlugin.js* plugin for it from *cloudformatter.com*. I followed all the steps from http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage

But when i try to export, PDF get generates with blank square box.

[image]

I'm loading the google chart from jquery ajax call. Can any body tell me what could be the issue ?

Here is a sample code without ajax call -

```
 <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="margin-right: 7px;" onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('chart_container', {render: 'download', filename: 'Years_Build', mimeType: 'application/pdf'});">Export</button>
    <div id="chart_container">
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
          ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
          ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
          ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
          ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
                                                            }
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
```

Comment: You have to post a minimalistic sample replicating your issue...

Comment: I tried a different way to export Google Graph to PDF with same plugin.
Here are the instructions to implement it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102992/save-google-charts-as-pdf

And here is the example -
http://jsfiddle.net/zvx6eb7e/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the SVG namespace which needs to be added. If you examine the sample fiddle on their site for each chart you will see a function that adds the namespace after the chart is drawn.

For example, see http://jsfiddle.net/w1rpjxoe/

You would see this function:

```
function AddNamespace(){
  var svg = jQuery('#chart_div svg');
  svg.attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
  svg.css('overflow','visible');
}
```

It is called from this Listener:

```
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', AddNamespace);
```

What this does is add the missing SVG namespace to the chart SVG that Google charts does not do but @cloudformatter requires.

Comment: If that is not the issue, it is one of them. If there is still an issue, post the actual call you are making to the plug-in Javascript so we can see what div you are printing and what additional options you are passing.